# Laravel 5: how to decode json returned from ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5

I am working on a shopping cart application. when the user clicks the `add to cart` button, I want the ajax call to my controller function to return two values: `totalPrice` and `totalQty` which are to be displayed on the page. I have been able to return the values in as json: `{"totalPrice":100,"totalQty":1}`. Now how do i extract the `totalPrice` and `totalQty` to display on different parts of the page. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<a data-id="{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-success addToCart" >Add to cart</a>
```

Here is code for my ajax:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('.addToCart').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).data('id');

            $.ajax({
                url  : "{{ route('product.addToCart') }}",
                type : "POST",
                data : {
                    'id' : id,
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                success:function(data){
                   alert(data); // returns {"totalPrice":100,"totalQty":1}
                   // how do I decode and display data returned here?
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Here is my controller method:

```
public function addToCart(Request $request){
    $post = $request->all();
    $id = $post['id'];
    $product = Product::find($id);

    //some code is excluded to simplify this function

    $total_price = 100;
    $total_qty = 1;
    $vals = array('totalPrice' => $total_price,'totalQty' => $total_qty);
    $vals = json_encode($vals);
    echo $vals;
    exit();

}
```

This is where json values returned are supposed to be displayed:

```
<a href="{{ route('product.shoppingCart') }}">
Cart - <span class="cart-amunt">//display amount here</span> 
<span class="product-count"> //display totalQty here </span>
</a>
```

Comment: try JSON.parse(data);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var response = JSON.parse(data);

alert(response.col_name);  // will print the column value
```

[Parse json documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Answer (score 2):

when you use ajax method for send and receive , you better using from datatype

if using `dataType:'json',`  , This problem was solved .

and you can using in success :

```
success:function(data){
  alert(data.totalPrice); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are returning encoded json data from Laravel then in jQuery you can use `dataType:'json'` while making ajax request and it will convert response data to json itself, you don't need to convert to JSON manually, jQuery will do it for you.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType:"json",
    data : {
        'id' : id,
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },
    ...
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for full list of values that you can use in `dataType`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Laravel's json response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses). If you merely echo it out in your controller, it will be returned as string, if you return it as a json response. You can just refer it as `data.totalPrice` in your javascript.

Thus you can do something like this:

```
 success:function(data){
               $(".product-count").html(data.totalQty);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.parse()` in case you are `json_encode()` encoding in the controller. If you dont do `json_encode()` in the controller then you can access response values without `JSON.parse()`